# Cant get the catch statement to catch the custom exception

Tags: .net

i have created a custom exception in the business layer and also using wcf layer where I am calling the methods in the business layer then in another website i am calling the method from wcf. i can see the message that i wrote in custom exception but the program goes staright to exception (the second catch block) instead of hitting my first catch block(where the custom exception is) when i hover over the exception i see my message but it's inside something called faultexception which i am not familiar with. and in there under details..there i see type= CanOnlyApplyOnceException. here is my code:

```
 protected void AddNewApplication()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var proxy = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient())
            {
                proxy.AddApplication(new Application
                {
                    Credentials = 2,
                    Comments = txtComments.Text,
                });
            }
        }
        catch (CanOnlyApplyOnceException c)
        {
            ErrorSummary.AddError(c.Message, this);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "There has been an error.  Please try again";
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you see a type that you're not familiar with, the first thing to do is check MSDN.

Comment: I did that and spent time doing what i found in msdn but didnt work

Comment: they said instead of throwing like this: throw new Canonlyapplyoneexception do throw new FaultException<Canonlyapplyonveexception>(new canonlyapplyonceexception(message)...which i did but that didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Add FaultContract attribute on your method declaration on your WCF service like this:

   ```
   [OperationContract]
   [FaultContract((typeof(CanOnlyApplyOnceException))]
   void AddApplication(Application your_variable_name);
   ```

Then make sure you throw exception of type CanOnlyApplyOnceException.

2. Change your catch block to this:

   ```
   catch (FaultException<CanOnlyApplyOnceException> c)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199.aspx) is thrown on the client if a service throws an exception.

Depending on the service, you may be able to write

```
    catch (FaultException<CanOnlyApplyOnceException> c)
    {
        ErrorSummary.AddError(c.Detail.Message, this);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah i did this already and still goes straight to Exception.

Comment: Then you need to catch the non-generic `FaultException`.

Comment: this is the detail inside exception {"You can only apply once!"} [System.ServiceModel.FaultException<System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail>]: {"You can only apply once"} Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} HelpLink: null InnerException: null Message: "You can only apply once" Source: "mscorlib" and also the type CanOnlyApplyOnce is inside the details of this. How do i get the type?

Comment: You need to check `ex.Detail.Type`.